# SQL cursor applying changes to the whole table and not just the selection

Tags: sql, database-cursor

I am trying to iterate through a table and apply changes to selected values in a column. The curser I use should change a value in the 'COMMENTS' column, but only if the 'DESPATCHNO' starts with AB (see example table below).

```
 Original Table                     Altered Table
```

| DESPATCHNO | COMMENTS |
| --- | --- |
| AA001 | Null |
| AA002 | Null |
| AB001 | Null |
| AB002 | Null |
| 10001 | Null |
| 10002 | Null |
| 20001 | Null |
| 20002 | Null |

```
 Altered Table
```

| DESPATCHNO | COMMENTS |
| --- | --- |
| AA001 | Null |
| AA002 | Null |
| AB001 | TEST |
| AB002 | TEST |
| 10001 | Null |
| 10002 | Null |
| 20001 | Null |
| 20002 | Null |

When I run my SQL script, the cursor applies the changes to the entire table, and not only to the selected/specified values.

I have tried it a couple of ways, and I have pasted two of the 'working' scripts bellow.
P.S. The second select statement is just to show the changes made, and although it only shows the correct records, all the records (in the entire table) have been changed.

**Script 1:**

```
Declare @lineId varchar(30) //This is for storing the DESPATCHNO
Declare @colChange varchar(254) //This is for storing the COMMENTS

Declare ChangeCursor CURSOR FOR
Select DESPATCHNO,COMMENTS from DESPATCHSEND where DESPATCHNO like 'AB%' //This is to select only the records starting with AB 

Open ChangeCursor

Fetch Next from ChangeCursor into @lineId, @colChange

While(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
Begin

    if(@lineId LIKE 'EB%') //I thought adding an IF statement would help
    Begin
        Update DESPATCHSEND set COMMENTS = 'TEST'
    End

Fetch Next from ChangeCursor into @lineId, @colChange

Select @lineId,@colChange //This is to show the changes made

End

CLOSE ChangeCursor
DEALLOCATE ChangeCursor
```

**Script 2:**

```
Declare @lineId varchar(30) //This is for storing the DESPATCHNO
Declare @colChange varchar(254) //This is for storing the COMMENTS

Declare ChangeCursor CURSOR FOR
Select DESPATCHNO,COMMENTS from DESPATCHSEND where DESPATCHNO like 'EB%' //This is to select only the records starting with AB

Open ChangeCursor

Fetch Next from ChangeCursor into @lineId, @colChange

While(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
Begin

    Update DESPATCHSEND set COMMENTS = 'TEST'
    
    Fetch Next from ChangeCursor into @lineId, @colChange

    Select @lineId,@colChange //This is to show the changes made

End

CLOSE ChangeCursor
DEALLOCATE ChangeCursor
```

I have watched various tutorials and have tried various solutions I found on Stack Overflow, every time with the same result. For some reason I cannot get the curser to change *only* the records that start with AB - every time the curser changes the entire table.

Please note that I am not an expert in SQL, I am still in the learning phase.

Comment: Don't expect a SELECT without an ORDER BY to return rows in any specific order. Can even change from time to time.

Comment: update statement is not restricted to the cursor.  So you are updating all the rows in the table twice, once for each matching row in your cursor.

But you don't need a cursor for this, just a where clause in your update statement.
UPDATE DESPATCHSEND SET COMMENTS = 'Test' WHERE DESPATCHNO LIKE 'AB%'